# Numeric variable scope in Python closure (Python v2.5.2)

Tags: python

I have a nested function where I am trying to access variables assigned in the parent scope.  From the first line of the `next()` function I can see that `path`, and `nodes_done` are assigned as expected. `distance`, `current`, and `probability_left` have no value and are causing a `NameError` to be thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I access and modify the values of `current`, `distance`, and `probability_left` from the `next()` function?

```
def cheapest_path(self):
    path = []
    current = 0
    distance = 0
    nodes_done = [False for _ in range(len(self.graph.nodes))]
    probability_left = sum(self.graph.probabilities)

    def next(dest):
        log('next: %s -> %s distance(%.2f), nodes_done(%s), probability_left(%.2f)' % (distance,self.graph.nodes[current],self.graph.nodes[dest],str(nodes_done),probability_left))
        path.append((current, distance, nodes_done, probability_left))

        probability_left -= self.graph.probabilities[current]
        nodes_done[current] = True
        distance = self.graph.shortest_path[current][dest]
        current = dest

    def back():
        current,nodes_done,probability_left = path.pop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Python's nested scopes work, you can never *assign* to a variable in the parent scope, unless it's global (via the `global` keyword). This changes in Python 3 (with the addition of `nonlocal`), but with 2.x you're stuck.

Instead, you have to sort of work around this by using a datatype which is stored by reference:

```
def A():
    foo = [1]
    def B():
        foo[0] = 2 # since foo is a list, modifying it here modifies the referenced list
```

Note that this is why your list variables work - they're stored by reference, and thus modifying the list modifies the original referenced list. If you tried to do something like `path = []` inside your nested function, it wouldn't work because that would be actually assigning to `path` (which Python would interpret as creating a new local variable `path` inside the nested function that *shadows* the parent's `path`).

One option that is sometimes used is to just keep all of the things that you want to persist down into the nested scope in a `dict`:

```
def A():
    state = {
        'path': [],
        'current': 0,
        # ...
    }

    def B():
        state['current'] = 3
```

Comment: +1. In this particular case though, I'd suggest using a `dict` instead of a list for clarity's sake.

Comment: @Cameron I was actually just adding a note about that. :P

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but was making sure I wasn't missing something in the language

Comment: This is incorrect: the `nonlocal` keyword allows writing to variables in an outer but non-global scope.  It's unfortunately only available in Python 3, which is a bit inexplicable as I believe this is purely a syntax issue and doesn't even require additional VM support; but it's there.  It really needs to be backported to 2.x, as it'll be years before most people will be using 3.x...

Comment: @Glenn: The vast majority of Python users are on 2.x; thus it typically makes sense to give the answer that applies to that version.

Comment: It's important to specify when answers are strongly version-specific; anyone who needs the information probably doesn't already know it.  Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that python does not have proper lexical scoping support. If it did, there would have to be more syntax to support the behavior (i.e. a var/def/my keyword to declare the variable scope).

Barring actual lexical scoping, the best you can do is store the data in an environment data structure. One simple example would be a list, e.g.:

```
def cheapest_path(self):
    path = []
    path_info = [0, 0]
    nodes_done = [False for _ in range(len(self.graph.nodes))]
    probability_left = sum(self.graph.probabilities)

    def next(dest):
        distance, current = path_info
        log('next: %s -> %s distance(%.2f), nodes_done(%s), probability_left(%.2f)' %     (distance,self.graph.nodes[current],self.graph.nodes[dest],str(nodes_done),probability_left))
        path.append((current, distance, nodes_done, probability_left))

        probability_left -= self.graph.probabilities[current]
        nodes_done[current] = True
        path_info[0] = self.graph.shortest_path[current][dest]
        path_info[1] = dest

    def back():
        current,nodes_done,probability_left = path.pop()
```

You can do this or do inspect magic. For more history on this read this [thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-July/066862.html).

Comment: You'd also need to modify `probability_left`. In addition, it'd probably be better to use a `dict` rather than a list, because `[0]` and `[1]` are far less descriptive than `['current']` and `['distance']`.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be working with Python 3, you can use the `nonlocal` statement ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal)) to make those variables exist in the current scope, e.g.:

```
def next(dest):
    nonlocal distance, current, probability_left
    ...
```